# how to access ODOO POS Coding by Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, odoo, pos

if I want to customize any app e.g POS by editing in coding. So is it possible and if is it possible then how to access their coding. because i am unable to find its coding I have installed Pycharm for it but didn't find code of app(POS)

Answer (score 0):

You could see the Odoo code at: [github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons/). You could clone or download that repository into you local filesystem. Also there is another URL for [nightly builds](https://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/src/) where you could download the packaged source code.

With the source code inplace you could import it into Pycharm just by using the menu: File/Open...